# Cakephp How to add two data items to empty option

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I am new to cake php . I have following code

echo $this->Form->input('dob', array('type' => 'date', 'empty' => "Select",  'label' => 'Birthday', 'dateFormat' => 'MDY', 'minYear' => date('Y') - 120, 'maxYear' => date('Y'), 'selected' => array('month' => '','day' => '', 'year' => '')));

the above code displays select box which contains select then followed by month,day,year. Now I need to add N/A(Not applicable) option to it. In select box it should be like select then N/A then months, similarly select then N/A then day,select then N/A then year.

In select box it should be
select N/A Month1 month2 month3...
select N/A day1 day2 day3...
select N/A year1 year2 year3

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code adds N/A option

echo $this->Form->input('dob', array('type' => 'date', **'empty' => array('Select','N/A')**,  'label' => 'Birthday', 'dateFormat' => 'MDY', 'minYear' => date('Y') - 120, 'maxYear' => date('Y'), 'selected' => array('month' => '','day' => '', 'year' => '')));